# Thread::park failed invalid argument

Tags: android, automotive

I tried to do some periodic action in Android R automotive device by ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

1. There is my code:

   ```
   private static class NamedThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
       private final AtomicInteger mThreadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);
       private final String mNamePrefix;

       NamedThreadFactory(String namePrefix) {
           mNamePrefix = namePrefix + "-thread-";
       }

       @Override
       public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
           final Thread thread = new Thread(r, mNamePrefix + mThreadNumber.getAndIncrement());
           return thread;
       }
   }

   private ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mPopDataRefreshExecutor =
       new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1, new NamedThreadFactory("refreshPopData"));

   mPopDataRefreshExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new PopDataRefresher(),
       TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5),
       TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(10),
       TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
   ```
2. And then, it once raise some native signal 6 exception:

   Revision: '0'

   ABI: 'arm'

   Timestamp: 1912-01-03 13:32:13+0800

   pid: 9441, tid: 11146, name: RefreshPopData-  >>> com.demo <<<
   uid: 1010065

   signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------

Abort message: 'Failed to park: Invalid argument'

```
r0  00000000  r1  00002b8a  r2  00000006  r3  bb98eb00

r4  bb98eb14  r5  bb98eaf8  r6  000024e1  r7  0000016b

r8  bb98eb10  r9  bb98eb00  r10 bb98eb30  r11 bb98eb20

ip  00002b8a  sp  bb98ead0  lr  f1fa158f  pc  f1fa15a2
```

backtrace:

```
  #00 pc 000545a2  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+166) (BuildId: ced36bae419d8d9438cf6f91c6feea37)
  #01 pc 003a0f7d  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1980) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #02 pc 000085e1  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+488) (BuildId: d8f9959168f480e25050a2b6cf313736)
  #03 pc 003cff97  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Park(bool, long long)+1570) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #04 pc 003417e9  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Unsafe_park(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, unsigned char, long long)+440) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #05 pc 000edfc9  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+96) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #06 pc 0024e283  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos+818) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #07 pc 003914f7  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$DelayedWorkQueue.take+326) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #08 pc 003600dd  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (sun.nio.fs.UnixPath.getParent [DEDUPED]+36) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #09 pc 0034b265  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask+428) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #10 pc 0034c9ff  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker+222) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #11 pc 0034a0a7  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run+54) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #12 pc 001da039  /system/framework/arm/boot.oat (java.lang.Thread.run+64) (BuildId: 16090464612e7610f7b849552ef4a978eef87738)
  #13 pc 000e4bc5  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub_internal+68) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #14 pc 0045e97b  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art_quick_invoke_stub+250) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #15 pc 000ecffd  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::ArtMethod::Invoke(art::Thread*, unsigned int*, unsigned int, art::JValue*, char const*)+160) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #16 pc 0039ab77  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::(anonymous namespace)::InvokeWithArgArray(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, art::ArtMethod*, art::(anonymous namespace)::ArgArray*, art::JValue*, char const*)+54) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #17 pc 0039b881  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue const*)+300) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #18 pc 003d0e73  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::CreateCallback(void*)+982) (BuildId: b1931727e2af1deddf3d63be01bc9e06)
  #19 pc 0009c5e7  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+20) (BuildId: ced36bae419d8d9438cf6f91c6feea37)
  #20 pc 00055a97  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: ced36bae419d8d9438cf6f91c6feea37)
```

3. When I tried to add some log to solve this problem, it never happends again with same apk and same device.
4. Is any advice to deal with it, I tried to read AOSP code(https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:art/runtime/thread.cc;l=311?q=Thread::park) and find out this stack mean to futex something failed. But I have no idea what "Failed to park: Invalid argument" means.

Comment: This isn't a good way of doing periodic work on Android.  Android will frequently kill any app in the background.  If you need to do periodic work, look into JobScheduler, WorkManager, or even AlarmManager.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.
My app is a preset app, it can raise an resident process in ROM,so I can ignore background-kill.
I will try to replace ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with jobService.
But I think this stack shows something error happened in libart.so,can I do something further to figure out this error.